# AWS Cloudwatch Alarms - One alarm for multiple dimension values possible?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-sns, cloudwatch-alarms

In my AWS organization we have multiple (5+) accounts and a Cloudtrail trail for management events with Cloudwatch log group for all the accounts and regions in the org.

For the log group there is a series of generic metric filters setup, each with a Cloudwatch alarm. These are all tied to one or more SNS topics and associated subscriptions and all out of the box.

For example:

```
aws logs put-metric-filter --log-group-name CLOUDWATCH-LOG-GROUP --filter-name FILTER-NAME --metric-transformations metricName=METRIC-NAME,metricNamespace=NAMESPACE,metricValue=1 --filter-pattern '{ ($.eventName = ConsoleLogin) && ($.errorMessage = "Failed authentication") }'
```

Creates a metric filter for any failed logins on console for any of the accounts that sets the metric value to `1` when a match for the filter pattern is found in the log.

Paired with

```
aws cloudwatch put-metric-alarm --alarm-name METRIC-NAME-alarm --metric-name METRIC-NAME --statistic Sum --period 300 --threshold 1 --comparison-operator GreaterThanOrEqualToThreshold --evaluation-periods 1 --namespace NAMESPACE --alarm-actions SNS-TOPIC-ARN
```

This creates a simple alarm that fires an event to the SNS topic.

The major drawback here however is if my org account ID is #1234 and my worker account ID is #4321 and the failed login happens at the worker account, the Alarm that is sent refers only to the org account ID and I need to login and look to figure out where this happened.

Now, I can add a dimension to the `metric-transformation` to include something to help me differentiate (for example `recipientAccountId`). That would look something like

```
aws logs put-metric-filter --log-group-name CLOUDWATCH-LOG-GROUP --filter-name FILTER-NAME --metric-transformations metricName=METRIC-NAME,metricNamespace=NAMESPACE,metricValue=1,dimensions={"Account"=($.recipientAccountId)} --filter-pattern '{ ($.eventName = ConsoleLogin) && ($.errorMessage = "Failed authentication") }'
```

But, in order for the Cloudwatch alarm to trigger, it appears that the dimension must also be included there, it isn't possible to have one Alarm for all the possible `Value` that exist. **Which then seems to require one Alarm per `recipientAccountId` (ACCOUNT-ID in the below).**

Ex:

```
aws cloudwatch put-metric-alarm --alarm-name METRIC-NAME-alarm --metric-name METRIC-NAME --statistic Sum --period 300 --threshold 1 --comparison-operator GreaterThanOrEqualToThreshold --evaluation-periods 1 --dimensions Name=Account,Value=ACCOUNT-ID --namespace NAMESPACE --alarm-actions SNS-TOPIC-ARN
```

Is this correct?

All of this is really just to include some metadata with the alarm to let me know which Account triggered, is there a better solution?

Comment: Are you using Cloudtrail just for this purpose?

Comment: We are use Cloudtrail collect audit/security events in the cloud accounts, like bad login attempts, MFA missing on login, changes in security groups etc.

Answer (score 0):

[CloudWatch Metric Insights Alarms](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2022/12/amazon-cloudwatch-metrics-insights-alarms/) allows you to alarm on the aggregate (or worst single) metric from up to 10,000 metrics in a single alarm. In your case, alarm on the sum of login errors across all accounts and then use a Metric Insights query with a `GROUP BY recipientAccountId` to know which account id fired the alarm.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34336555)